# How to allow reload value in cck field?

Tags: entities

I have a problem.
I wish I achieve for my preloading fields Content Type (Type list). (pre loader like a webform).
Loading this list thereby synchronize on a table by the user.

I get to create my field and load the first time. But when you synchronize the table, it is necessary that the field starts to date.

How to allow reload value in cck field?

Thank

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find.

In my instance, I use :

```
 'allowed_values' => array(),
 'allowed_values_function' => '_get_list_catalogue',
```